# stable state of two separate queues and of merging queue

Tags: queueing-theory

if $n_{1}(t)$ is the total number of demands in two independent and similar $M/M/1$ queue with demand entry rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$, how can I prove that the probability of stable states are:
$$p(n_{1}(t)=n) = (n+1)(1-\rho)^2 .\rho ^n$$ that $n\ge0$ and $\rho=\lambda / \mu$.
and if we merge two queues and make a $M/M/2$ queue, how can I prove that in stable state :
$$p(n_{2}(t)=n) =(2(1-\rho)(\rho)^n)/(1+\rho)$$ if $n\ge0$ and $$p(n_{2}(t)=n) = (1-\rho)/(1+\rho)$$ if $n=0 $.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the limiting distributions of the first and second queues. Then by independence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N_1+N_2=n) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb P(N_1+N_2=n\mid N_1=k)\mathbb P(N_1=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb P(N_2=n-k)\mathbb P(N_1=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (1-\rho)\rho^{n-k}(1-\rho)\rho^k\\
&=(1-\rho)^2\rho^n\sum_{k=0}^n 1\\
&=(n+1)(1-\rho)^2\rho^n. 
\end{align}
The $M/M/2$ queue has detailed balance equations
\begin{align}
\mu\pi_1 &= \lambda\pi_0\\
2\mu\pi_n &= \lambda\pi_{n-1},\ n\geqslant 2.
\end{align}
This yields $\pi_1 = \frac\lambda\mu\pi_0=2\rho\pi_0$ and $\pi_n = \rho\pi_{n-1}$, hence $\pi_n = 2\rho^n\pi_0$ for $n\geqslant 1$. We compute $\pi_0$ by using $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n=1$:
$$
\pi_0 = \left(1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\rho^n \right)^{-1} = \frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho},
$$
and hence for $n\geqslant 1$,
$$
\pi_n = \frac{2(1-\rho)\rho^n}{1+\rho}.
$$